# What are the impacts of mashing with a low pH?

Tags: mash, sour, ph, lactobacillus

The general consensus seems to be that a mash pH of [5.2-5.6 is desired](http://howtobrew.com/book/section-3/understanding-the-mash-ph/residual-alkalinity-and-mash-ph). Beersmith even [says](http://beersmith.com/blog/2015/05/07/mash-ph-and-why-it-matters-for-all-grain-beer-brewing/) it's the difference between a good beer and a truly great one.

Most mention trouble with too high of a pH, but I'm wondering, what are the impacts of a much lower pH, like 4.5 or even 4.0?

I ask because adjusting the pH to make the environment favor lactobacillus using acidulated malt would be a pre-mash way of lowering the pH (rather than a post-mash method like adding phosphoric or lactic acid). I would prefer to use the acid malt, but it is pre-mash, so would like to understand the consequences.

At least according to [this experiment](http://brulosophy.com/2017/01/30/water-chemistry-pt-7-evaluating-the-impact-of-low-mash-ph-exbeeriment-results/), there's not much negative impact, but it's hardly definitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The enzymes beta-amylase and alpha-amylase have ideal ranges. Doesn't mean they will not work they just take longer if a little too high or low.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4460087/#!po=49.0826

**Basically what it says is that our brewing enzymes will still function until pH induced denaturing, which happens around pH 2.0** Though they lose a lot of functionality below 4.0 pH.

But for your application I would mash normally until saccrafication is done then add your acidulated malts at the end. Sparge once you've reached your desired pH.

Comment: But then you lose the conversion of the malt, but still probably preferable to adding acid directly.

Comment: @Wyrmwood acidulated malt is made by fermenting the kilned malt. For that to happen the sugars in the grain have already been made and mostly used by the lactobacillus, making the acid. I suspect Mashing late just to drop the pH would have little effect on OG.

Comment: Just one last nitpic - the article suggests the enzymes are still functional between 4.0–9.0 but your suggestion is still to add the acid malt post mash, why?

Comment: @Wyrmwood I suggested just in the interest of reducing your mash time.

Comment: There is a table floating around out there that depicts Alpha/Beta amylase activity by functions of temperature and pH.  I think John Palmer had it in his book "How to Brew"

Comment: @mreff555 that reference has a very narrow view of temp and pH. Basically only listing ideal ranges.

Comment: Well yes, but a broad range of ideal. We could speak of edge cases all day. However, Ireland is known for having some of the most basic conditions on earth. However they rarely exceed 8.6, and for good reason, are home to some of the most famous porters. There are some areas in various volcanic regions which have extremely acidic conditions but are not known for their amazing beers. I think that table is fully capable for most typical conditions.

Comment: @mreff555 you know why those areas are only,famous for certain styles right? Ireland can't make a good Pils but can dark beers because dark grains drop pH more than light. Many German waters have low pH that's why lighter beers work better. Waiting 2-3 times as long for a mash to complete because your pH is out of ideal ranges, isn't practical for a brewery. That being said you can make beer with ph issues, it just takes much longer. You do run into hard blocks when balancing time sensitive protient rests etc

Comment: I think you are missing the point. There are a few extremes out there, but they are edge cases. In most cases that chart is sufficient. You are right about Germany. However, the way I see it. That’s how new styles were historically invented. Overcoming issues. You’ve just illustrated that water pH was a major driver for that.

Comment: @mreff555 the opener what asking about an "edge case scenario" somthing not covered in palmers chart..... Idk how we got,on historical water debate.